# ActiveMq Producer is taking longer time to send JMS message to Destination queue

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

We are facing an issue, where sending a JMS message to a particular queue ,from camel java DSL route, taking almost 20 secs which is very bad response for us. Here running with only single thread, no multiple threads.

Could you please give some pointers, what could be reasons for the delay. Is it the scenario where producer got hung, due to producer flow control is enabled in ActiveMq broker configuration. if it is, how to deal with it?

Please find logs here:

> 015-11-13 12:25:43,733 | DEBUG | r[GET_QUERY_QUEUE] | JmsConfiguration
>   | 162 - org.apache.camel.camel-jms - 2.10.2.1-SNAPSHOT | Sending JMS
>   message to: temp-queue://ID:test-portal-01-53869-1447403844710-5:1:6
>   with message: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired =
>   false, messageId = null, originalDestination = null,
>   originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null,
>   transactionId = null, expiration = 1447406874046, timestamp = 0,
>   arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId =
>   Camel-ID-msc-01-58624-1447403845629-15-4289
>
> 2015-11-13 12:26:03,355 | DEBUG | r[GET_QUERY_QUEUE] |
>   TemporaryQueueReplyManager       | 162 - org.apache.camel.camel-jms -
>   2.10.2.1-SNAPSHOT | Received reply message with correlationID [Camel-ID-msc-pcen-portal-01-58624-1447403845629-15-4289] ->
>   ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 70773, responseRequired = true,
>   messageId = ID:msc-pcen-portal-01-53869-1447403844710-5:1:91:83:1,
>   originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId =
>   ID:msc-pcen-portal-01-53869-1447403844710-5:1:91:83, destination =
>   temp-queue://test-portal-01-53869-1447403844710-5:1:6, transactionId =
>   null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1447406743733, arrival = 0,
>   brokerInTime = 1447406763354, brokerOutTime = 1447406763354,
>   correlationId =
>   Camel-ID-msc-01-58624-1447403845629-15-4289,

2015-11-13 12:25:39,046 | DEBUG | [RETRIEVAL_QUERY] | JmsConfiguration                 | 162 - org.apache.camel.camel-jms - 2.10.2.1-SNAPSHOT | Sending JMS message to: queue://GET_QUERY_QUEUE with message: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, messageId = null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null, expiration = 1447406870890, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = Camel-ID-msc-01-58624-1447403845629-15-4289

2015-11-13 12:25:43,624 | DEBUG | r[GET_QUERY_QUEUE] | EndpointMessageListener          | 162 - org.apache.camel.camel-jms - 2.10.2.1-SNAPSHOT | Endpoint[jmsvm://queue:GET_QUERY_QUEUE?concurrentConsumers=1&maxConcurrentConsumers=10] consumer received JMS message: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 70677, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:msc-pcen-portal-01-53869-1447403844710-5:1:125:101:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:msc-pcen-portal-01-53869-1447403844710-5:1:125:101, destination = queue://GET_QUERY_QUEUE, transactionId = null, expiration = 1447406874046, timestamp = 1447406739046, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1447406743623, brokerOutTime = 1447406743623, correlationId = Camel-ID-msc-01-58624-1447403845629-15-4289,

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are doing request/reploy over JMS by mistake and that bt default uses a 20 sec timeout to wait for a reply message. If you want to just send a message to a queue in fire and forget style, then make sure to set the message exchange pattern to InOnly.

See about these EIPs

- http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html
- http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, Claus lnsen.

Comment: Camel route defined on GET_QUERY_QUEUE is InOut and it is intentional.       But within the camel route, how come there is a 20 secs delay between when it try to send a message to temp-queue and time temp-queue gets the message. This 20 secs time is not constant, sometimes it is 8-10 secs, but still it very long!!  I have updated logs above. It looks either the producer blocked send a message to a queue or consumer/route is not able respond quickly. is not it?